How to migrate my tensor flow gradle plugin?
While trying to migrate my grade for tensor flow I get this error mess:

plugin id 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite' is invalid: Plugin id contains invalid char ':' (only ASCII alphanumeric characters, '.', '_' and '-' characters are valid)

How to rewrite it without the semicolon?
My current plugins definition:
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false
    id "org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite" version "0.1.100" apply false
}
``


What migration are you doing exactly? That looks like a library, not a plugin
